# AS3 + One Global Instance vs. Multiple Instances

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

My main document class presently has an Instance of my Assets class which is designed to be the go-to for all image loading and accessing. It's my one place where I can embed all of my images and go from there. My question is, is it better to have one global instance located in my Main Document class and then whenever I create a new instance of a class that will then utilize the Assets instance, pass a reference to the main document class, or should the classes be responsible for instantiating their own Assets class?

I hope this makes sense. I'm looking in terms of proper coding, efficiency and also less memory usage.

Comment: What you have described with your `Assets` class is almost the same as what I have done in my game framework with [this `Library` class](https://github.com/MartyWallace/Sentinel/blob/master/src/sentinel/framework/Library.as). I think it's a pretty logical way to go about it. I would not have each individual entity manage its own assets, especially because you only need one of each asset to reference (especially in newer frameworks like Starling where only one Bitmap is used as a reference for drawing instances of it to the screen).

Comment: it all depends on what are the other requirements. for example some assets might be needed in some cases but not in others so a lazy-loading scheme is better and a lazy loading scheme is better handled by each specific task and so on

Comment: I say make your `Assets` a static class, and reference there using static methods. Of course, all loading and preparing should be handled inside, and a collection of assets (bitmap data, sprites, shapes, whatever) should be available via `Assets` interface. In this case, your assets will be located in one place, and in case there are *many* assets shared by parts of your program, they will be loaded only once.